# C++ Cast two types with different memory layout

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the way to cast two types that have the same fields but in a different order (or even some of them missing) without copying.

For example, if we have the following structures:

```
typedef struct Foo {
  int age;
  float height;
  char* name;
} Foo;

typedef struct Bar {
  float height;
  float weight;  
  char* name;
  int age;
} Bar;
```

Is there any way to cast Bar into Foo without having to make an intermediate copy?

```
Bar bar;
Foo foo;

bar = foo;
```

Moreover, would it be possible to do it with a pointer cast?

```
Bar *bar;
Foo foo;

bar = &foo
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Salva

Comment: No. The point of a cast is "You see that memory over there? It's this type now, just trust me." If the memory doesn't match the type you say it is, you are in for a whole heap of trouble.

Comment: Why the C tag? Note that the `typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;` is unnecessary in C++ -- you can just `struct Foo { ... } ;`

Comment: There is no way to cast here.  You'll need to make a copy.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could potentially use inheritance, such as `struct Bar : Foo { float weight; };`

Comment: It will not be possible to cast two types that have the same field types and names in a different order without copying.  It isn't even allowed to cast two types that have the same field types and names in the same order without copying, without resorting to undefined behavior and getting unlucky by having it appear to work.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Those are unrelated types.

You can either copy the data from the first object into the second or, in some limited cases, use some pointer magic to pretend that the first object has the type of the second. This is not one of those cases.

Fortunately, copying ints and floats is cheap and depending on your circumstances may not actually involve any activities at runtime (compilers are smart!).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is a simplified version of the actual problem. The actual type can have other structures inside, and the copy would be made on the critical path, so the copy can get pretty expensive in some cases.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink some of that design then.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly like that. You cannot make a pointer of a type point to a unrelated type, this would be a violation of the aliasing rule.

You could do that with a union if both type had a common initial sequence. However, you do not have that: some of the first members are not the same types.

Here's an example of your structs with the common initial sequence:

```
struct Foo {
    char const* name;
    int age;
    float height;
};

struct Bar {
    char const* name;
    int age;
    float height;

    float weight;
};

union Foobar {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
};

auto const foobar = Foobar{Bar{}};

// can access foo even though bar is initialized.
// a whole foo is a common initial sequence of bar.
Foo const* foo = foobar.foo;
```

You could also simply put the common member in a parent class:

```
struct common {
    char const* name;
    int age;
    float height;
};

struct Foo : common {
    // whatever
};

struct Bar : common {
    // whatever
};
```